Using the keras API in Tensorflow 2.x
I have the problem, that i can't access the keras API with tensorflow. Using the API should be possible, as it is also documented in the keras API section in the tensorflow docs.
When I try to import the module "tensorflow.keras" or try to use "tf.keras" in my program, it just says "Import 'tensorflow.keras' could not be resolved'. I've read that it's a VSCode specific problem.
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Lambda, TimeDistributed

And all these imports, except the import tensorflow as tf cannot be resolved.
Does somebody know how to fix this issue?
P.S. I use VSCode as my code editor and python version 3.10.11

add more details please

How did you installed tensorflow?

@Ivan I've installed tensorflow using the pip command

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you try running the code? Your IDE (VSCode) not being able to resolve an import is not a critical issue.

Which Tensorflow version are you using? Also, Could you please verify that you have followed the mentioned steps in this TF install official docs to install tensorflow in your system.
